# Primefaces : Datatable : contextMenu

Tags: primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

I am using a datatable with a contextMenu (Primefaces).
Datatable selection allows me to get the row, but how to get the column, please?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use JS to perform this action

Comment: Hi Dennis, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: I am a beginner in JS. PLEASE can you help me ?